# How to get the number of individual unread messages of PubNub?

Tags: objective-c, swift3, pubnub

I'm using pubnub Services to add chat functionality to my App but i'm wondering if there is a way to get the individual number of unread messages. i'm using this link -> https://www.pubnub.com/docs/swift/data-streams-publish-and-subscribe

Comment: Have you checked this url? https://support.pubnub.com/support/discussions/topics/14000006329

Comment: @aBilal17 Thanks for your support . I am checking.

Comment: @aBilal17 I have checked and this link says that total unread messages count but my requirement is individual unread messages not total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished using **[PubNub Functions](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/blocks/tutorials/hello-world?devrel_so=how-to-get-the-number-of-individual-unread-messages-of-pubnub)**. Functions are your own scripts that run automatically in the cloud when a message is published on one or many PubNub Channels.

It has a key-value store with `increment`, `decrement`, and `retrieve` functionality. This can be used very intuitively with an unread message pattern on PubNub.

**Channel:** room.*

**Event:** On-Before Publish

```
// Access to Distributed Database
const db = require('kvstore');
export default (request) => { 
    // Conventionally build the Key ID based on the request parameters and channel name.
    let counterId = request.channels[0] + '/' + request.params.uuid;
    // Increment or Decrement the unread message counter
    let method = request.message.read ? -1 : 1;
    // Increment/Decrement and read the unread message counter
    return db.incrCounter( counterId,  method ).then(()=>{
        return db.getCounter(counterId).then((counter) => {
            request.message.unread = counter || 0;
            return request.ok();
        });
    });
}
```

**Following this [official guide](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/track-read-unread-messages-with-pubnub-functions/?devrel_so=how-to-get-the-number-of-individual-unread-messages-of-pubnub)** you can integrate this new functionality into an existing app.